# htaccess RewriteRule not handling case

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Platform: Windows 7 Pro 64 bit

I have Apache 2.2 setup on my development machine (basically a WAMP setup).  I have several installs of Code Igniter based websites in the main htdocs.  However, I am getting stuck on handling case for sub directories under the main htdocs directory.

Here is where I am having issues with .htaccess (located in the /CILearn directory under htdocs):

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /CILearn/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /CILearn/index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

The sub directory is CILearn under htdocs.  So the URL looks like this:

```
    localhost/CILearn
    localhost/CILearn/site
    localhost/cilearn
```

Now this works and "site" is a controller so the redirect for index.php is working.

This does not work:

```
    localhost/cilearn/site
```

Can someone please explain where these rules should and why it is not handling case?

Comment: I am sorry folks.  It turns out it is all an issue with CodeIgniter.  It turns out using: $config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';  instead of: $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; Is what was needed.  So this really has little to do with Rewrite rules for Apache.  So I want to ask the moderators.  Should I delete this question or reword it?

Answer (score 1):

remove

```
RewriteBase /CILearn/
```

and test  it again , see this page http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase for more information about `RewriteBase`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /CILearn/index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Where are you placing .htaccess?  I just tried this without RewriteBase and I am still getting the same error on: http://localhost/cilearn/site

Comment: @Demolishun i put htaccess on root and create folder `CILearn` and create `index.php` on it

Comment: I tried moving it to the root "htdocs" and it did not work.  The funny thing is I have Rewrite logging turned on in Apache and it acts like it is taking the same paths.  So maybe the rewrite it working fine, but there is an error somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen, when your file system paths are case sensitive. You have two options here.

Use [`mod_speling`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html) in the root dir .htaccess (*not* /CILearn/.htaccess)

```
CheckSpelling on
CheckCaseOnly on
```

Be sure `mod_speling` is activated with something like

```
LoadModule speling_module /path/to/apache2/modules/mod_speling.dll
```

Alternatively, you can add a [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) fixing the case for `cilearn`. This must be done in the root dir .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cilearn/(.*) /CILearn/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: @faa You don't need `RewriteBase` as long as you substitute absolute URLs. So yes, you can remove it, but it doesn't hurt either.